# Events not working after saving code (on window deserialization)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

I have a custom `EditorWindow`, auxPanel (`ScriptableObject`) and a lot of regular classes, which are drawing themselves on the panel. And I have various events in these classes. When I launch the window - instances of the classes are subscribing on some events and it works fine. But when I change something in my code and save it - *Unity* recompiles scrips (*Unity* serializes and deserializes data during compilation) and all events stop working. Examlpe:

MainWindow:

```
public class MainWindow : EditorWindow  {

    public static MainWindow Instance;
    public AuxPanel auxPanel;

    [MenuItem("Examples/MainWindow")]
    static void InitAndRun() {
        if (Instance == null) {            
            Init();
        } else {            
            GetWindow<MainWindow>();
            Instance.Focus();
        }                
    }    

    private void OnEnable() {
        if (Instance == null) Instance = GetWindow<MainWindow>();        
    }

    private static void Init(String initForm = null) {            
        MainWindow mainWindow = GetWindow<MainWindow>();
        Instance = mainWindow;                                    
        mainWindow.InitializeInstance(initForm);
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    private void InitializeInstance(String initForm) {     
        auxPanel = CreateInstance<AuxPanel>().Initialize();   
    }

    private void OnGUI() {
        auxPanel.Draw();
    }
}
```

AuxPanel:

```
public class AuxPanel : ScriptableObject {

    public Rect DrawRect = new Rect(50, 20, 140, 140);

    [SerializeField]
    public ElementWithSubscribing myElement { get; set; }
    public UnityAction<Vector2> PositionChange = delegate { };

    public AuxPanel Initialize() {
        myElement = new ElementWithSubscribing(Vector2.zero, this);
        return this;
    }

    public void Draw() {
        GUI.Label(DrawRect, "", "GroupBox");
        myElement.Draw();
        // fire event
        PositionChange(DrawRect.position);
    }
}
```

ElementSubscriber:

```
[Serializable]
public class ElementWithSubscribing {

    public Rect DrawRect = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 50);

    public ElementWithSubscribing() { }
    public ElementWithSubscribing(Vector2 position) { }
    public ElementWithSubscribing(Vector2 position, AuxPanel auxPanel) {
        auxPanel.PositionChange += UpdatePosition;
    }

    protected void UpdatePosition(Vector2 designerPosition) {
        Debug.Log("event works!");
        DrawRect.position = designerPosition; 
    }

    public void Draw() {
        GUI.Button(DrawRect, "MyElement");
    }
}
```

After saving code - `ElementWithSubscribing` lose its subscribtion to `auxPanel.PositionChange`.

How to save the event? Or how to restore it after compiling?
I have a lot of events in this class and in the others, that's why temporary reattach an event to some aux object is not an option.

---

P.S. And sometimes after compilation the code above gives me 2 windows.

[image]
How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out all simple

When *Unity* recompiles scripts, it serializes and deserializes data. So, after deserializing it creates instances from saved serialized data and populates objects with the saved values.

When *Unity* creates an instance of `MonoBehaviour`/`ScriptableObject` derived class, it calls the **default constructor** to create the managed object. In my case it's `public ElementWithSubscribing() { }`. That's why an event is no longer worked.